# Why are the sequence spaces denoted by $\ell^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I have read functional analysis and metric spaces and conceptually, I have no problem at all with the sequence spaces. However, I do wonder why do sequence spaces are denoted by $\ell^p$?

Comment: Probably in honour to Henri Lebesgue, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think so too. Spaces of Lebesgue integrable functions are denoted by $L^p$, probably the $L$ comes from Lebesgue. $\ell^p$ is just a special case (a discrete case) of it.

Comment: My also unreferenced answer.  First there was the space $L$ of integrable function.  And the space $M$ of bounded functions.  Perhaps this $L$ was for Lebesgue?  Then a generalization $L^p$.  So $L$ became $L^1$ and $M$ became $L^\infty$.  Finally, certain sequence spaces were considered "analogous" to them, and denoted $l^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the notation is in honor of H. Lebesgue. If $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a [measure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space), then we can define the $p$-space of integrable functions as $$L^p(\mu)=\{f:X\to\mathbb{C}:\int_X|f|^pd\mu<\infty\}$$
Now there is a special measure that we can define on $\mathbb{N}$, called the counting measure: if $E\subset\mathbb{N}$, then $\mu(E)=$ how many elements $E$ has. It can be easily proved that $\mu$ is a measure and that $\ell^p=L^p(\mu)$, hence these spaces come from a large variety of spaces, called the $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: Another unreferenced answer.  I think the notation $l^p$ is older than the notation $L^p(\mu)$ for measures other than Lebesgue measure on a domain in $\mathbb R^n$.